# How to find diffrence between two UTC time in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, time

I have two dates in UTC format i.e **Sat, 05 Jan 2019 12:58:53 GMT** and **Sat, 05 Jan 2019 13:07:54 GMT**. I need to find the time difference between both dates.So far i have tried below code

```js
function timeDifference(date1, date2) {
  var difference = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
  console.log("difference-0--0", difference)
  var daysDifference = Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
  difference -= daysDifference * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

  var hoursDifference = Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60 / 60);
  difference -= hoursDifference * 1000 * 60 * 60

  var minutesDifference = Math.floor(difference / 1000 / 60);
  difference -= minutesDifference * 1000 * 60

  var secondsDifference = Math.floor(difference / 1000);

  console.log('difference = ' + daysDifference + ' day/s ' + hoursDifference + ' hour/s ' + minutesDifference + ' minute/s ' + secondsDifference + ' second/s ');
}
timeDifference(new Date('Sat, 05 Jan 2019 12:58:53 GMT'), new Date('Sat, 05 Jan 2019 13:07:54 GMT'))
```

it works fine when I pass Sat, 05 Jan 2019 12:58:53 GMT and Sat, 05 Jan 2019 5:07:54 GMT.

Comment: Is there any case its failing? Are you expecting more cleaner solution?

Comment: yes... it's failing when I pass time in 24 hours format i.e Sat, 05 Jan 2019 12:58:53 GMT and Sat, 05 Jan 2019 5:07:54 GMT. it should've given me output 0 days, 0 hours, 9 minutes, 1 second but its giving me  -1 day/s 23 hour/s 50 minute/s 59 second/s

Comment: When difference is between 0 and -1 (exclusively), `Math.floor` returns -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try test my solution:

```js
    function timeDifference(date1, date2) {

        let chage = 0;

        let difference = Math.abs(date1.setMilliseconds(0) - date2.setMilliseconds(0)) / 1000;

        let days = Math.floor(difference / (60 * 60 * 24));

        chage = difference % (60 * 60 * 24);

        let hours = Math.floor(chage / (60 * 60));

        chage = chage % (60 * 60);

        let minutes = Math.floor(chage / 60);

        let seconds = chage % 60;

        console.log("days:", days, "hours:", hours, "minutes:", minutes, "seconds:", seconds)

    }
    timeDifference(new Date('Sat, 05 Jan 2019 12:58:53 GMT'), new Date('Sat, 05 Jan 2019 13:07:54 GMT'))
```